# Hanoi algoritm first recursion step?

Tags: algorithm

I know this algoritm in theory.

Lets assume we have three disks and we want to move disks from A to C rods.

First move `n-1` disks from `A` to `B` using `C`
Then move last big disk to `C`
After all move all disks from `B` to C using `A`

I dont get why using fist recursion `honoi(n, A, C, B)` we move all disks from `A` to `C`.

Lets make iterations:

**First step:**

`n - 1 -> 2`, it means we get a second disk from stack of disks:

```
Disk 1
Disk 2 -> get this
-------
Disk 3
```

And move it to the empty rod:

```
Disk 1       Destination rod    
------ 
Disk 3                        Disk 2
```

**Second step:**

We get next dist `Disk 1`

```
------       Destination rod    Disk 1
Disk 3                          Disk 2
```

**Third step:**
Then move `Disk 3` to `Destination rod`"

```
-----  Disk 3   Disk 1
                Disk 2
```

What do we next?

We continue the same operation for `Disk 1, Disk 2` using empty rod, excluding `Disk 2` because `n - 1` right?

---

**Start again from** `n - 1` for **third** rod, after movement it comes to:

```
Disk 1 Disk 3 Disk 2
```

We need move all to the second rod, right?

**Step 1:**

```
Disk 1 Disk 2
       Disk 3
```

**Step 2 (finish):**

```
   Disk 1
   Disk 2
   Disk 3
```

So, I can not get how we know that we must move from the `third` rod and second step from the `first` rod to complete algoritm?

Do you know how to visualizate this algoritm by steps? I dont get how we choose empty rod...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MattTimmermans is, of course, correct in stating that recursion is not necessary to solve the Towers of Hanoi. But I think that the standard recursive solution is elegant and reveals the structure of the solution. So it's worth spending a few minutes coming to grips with it.

First of all, the following statement from your question is not a correct interpretation:

> First step: n - 1 -> 2, it means we get a second disk from stack of disks:

That's not what it means. hanoi(n, A, B, C) means "move **all** the disks from A to C using B as a temporary holding space. It does not mean "move disk N alone", which you cannot do because the rule of the game is that you can only move a disc which has nothing on top of it.

So what the recursive solution says is:

To move n discs from the source peg to the destination peg (using the other peg as a temporary):

1. Move the top *n*−1 discs to the temporary peg.
2. Move the disc *n* (which now has nothing on top of it) to the destination peg.
3. Move the *n*−1 discs from the temporary peg (where we put them at step 1) to the destination peg using the original peg as a temporary.

That's it.

What makes that solution recursive is that it doesn't spell out how to actually implement steps 1 and 3. (Step 2 is just a simple move.) We do steps 1 and 3 by using the same algorithm, except with one fewer disc. In effect, while we are performing steps 1 and 3, we are ignoring disc *n* (and bigger discs, if any). (Or, if you prefer, we are pretending that they are the floor.) That works out fine because they are all bigger than any of the discs we are moving, so they don't prevent us from putting one of the discs we are working on on top of them.

So, to move three discs:

```
Start: Goal is to move 3 discs from A to C
    ┌─┐ 
    └─┘ 
   ┌───┐ 
   └───┘ 
  ┌─────┐ 
  └─────┘    
 ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀    ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀    ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀

1. Move 2 discs from A to B (using C)


                 ┌─┐ 
                 └─┘ 
  ┌─────┐       ┌───┐ 
  └─────┘       └───┘     
 ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀    ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀    ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀

2. Move disc 3 from A to C


                 ┌─┐ 
                 └─┘ 
                ┌───┐       ┌─────┐
                └───┘       └─────┘
 ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀    ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀    ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀

3. Move 2 discs from B to C (using A)
                              ┌─┐ 
                              └─┘ 
                             ┌───┐ 
                             └───┘ 
                            ┌─────┐ 
                            └─────┘    
 ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀    ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀    ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
```

If for some reason the recursion seems confusing to you, pretend that you are doing the Towers of Hanoi and you have a friend who will help you. So you start by reading the instructions for moving three disks from peg A to peg C, and they say that the first thing you need to do is to move two disks from peg A to peg B. But you don't know how to do that, so you call your friend and they move the top two disks from peg A to peg B, so that you're in the second diagram above. Now the instructions say to move disk 3 from peg A to peg C, which you can do because disk 3 is now uncovered. So now you're at the third diagram, and again you have to move two disks. So you call your friend over again, and they move two disks from peg A to peg C for you, and the result is the bottom diagram, which means the problem has been solved.

So how did your friend manage to do that? Well, they are reading the same instructions as you are, so when you ask them to move two disks from peg A to peg B, they need to first move one disk (two minus one, right?) from peg A to their temporary peg, which is peg C. But that's easy, so they move the one peg. Then the instructions say to move the disk from peg A to peg B; again, no problem. And then they have to move the one disk from peg C to peg B. And the result is that they have moved two disks from A to B. Enhorabuena.

Now, let's step back a bit. Suppose you're the friend of someone who has been asked to solve the Tower of Hanoi with four disks, as with this [very pretty animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#/media/File:Tower_of_Hanoi_4.gif) on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi). Of course, they have the same instructions, so they had to start by moving three disks from peg A to peg B, and of course they asked you to do that, because you already have practice at moving three disks. So you do that for them, and then they lift disk 4 off of peg A and place it onto peg C. And then they call you back to move three disks from peg B to peg C.

Now, here's the cool part: You don't really need three people to do this. All you need is a bunch of post-it notes. Each time you have a subgoal, instead of finding a friend, you just write down what your current goal is and what step you are at in the instructions. Then you put the post-it note on top of the pile of post-its, and pretend you're the friend who has to do the move with one fewer disk. When you finish that task, you take the post-it off the top of the pile, and resume where you left off, tossing the post-it into the garbage.

That's recursion. It's simply a way of saying that when you solve a problem, you often have to do it pieces. And sometimes the solution to the pieces uses essentially the same method, but with smaller inputs.

Why don't you try it yourself? All you need is a few pieces of paper to represent the disks, and some post-it notes (or more bits of paper) to help your memory of where you are. Doing it by hand won't take you too long, and it's a lot easier to understand than reading words written in a foreign language.

Comment: move all the disks from A to C using B as a temporary holding space. It is not clear for me, move all disks at once? Beginning from which, from top or bottom?

Comment: @Jessy: The rules are simple: You cannot move a disk if there is something on top of it. You cannot put a disk on top of a smaller disk. That's it. You have to obey the rules. Move all the disks at once is not an option. Move the disk on the bottom is not an option.

Comment: Move the top n−1 disc to the temporary peg. Does it mean move one disk, is it first iteration? So one disk from the top of peg, right?

Comment: @Jessy: it means "use the algorithm to move n-1 discs from A to B". It means exactly that. If you know how to move n disks, you know how to move n-1 discs. (Of course, the easiest case is moving 0 disks. To move 0 disks you do nothing.)

Comment: @Jessy: Here's a nice animation.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi Note the configuration after seven moves. That was step 1 of the procedure for n=4. Watch that again, looking now at the first three moves, which are step 1 of the (recursive) procedure for n=3, but with different pegs. (It's easier if you do it yourself. You can make yourself a game in a few minutes, if you don't care too much about rough edges.)

Comment: Could explain one moment, we have three disks on first peg. 1, 2, 3 where 3 is biggest. When we so move operations to temp peg, we started form the bottom excluding last, biggest?

Comment: Pretend you have a friend helping you. I tell you to move three disks from peg A to peg C. So you tell your friend to move two disks from peg A to peg B. Then you move the disk on peg A to peg C and then you ask your friend to move two disks from peg B to peg C. How does your friend do what you ask them to do? How do they move two disks from peg A to peg B? They could ask their friend to move one disk from (one is two minus one, right?) from peg A to peg C. Then they move one disk from peg A to peg B and then they ask their friend to move one disk from peg C to peg B....

Comment: @Jessy: **You have to play by the rules**, we already agreed to that. You can only move the peg at the top of a pile.

Comment: I got the rules, how I can move all disks one by one form A peg, if I get disk from the to and put it to temp peg, in this case the second rule is not satisfied, because biggest disk is put over smaller.

Comment: @Jessy: you have to follow the same instructions. See my second last comment ("Pretend you have a friend..."), or read the edit I made to my answer. And please, DO TRY THIS YOURSELF. It will make much more sense than reading, and all it needs is a few pieces of paper.

Comment: In step `2. Move disc 3 from A to C` you have illustaration by you move two disks at once, instead by one,  if I get disks from the top and put it to peg then get next peg and put on the same peg, it is wrong, because biggest on the smaller

Comment: @jessy: I didn't draw every move. I'm trying to show you the recursive nature of the solution. What I drew were the results at every step of the top-level function. But the text tries to explain that. Did you read it?

Comment: Here's what I said: "What makes that solution recursive is that it doesn't spell out how to actually implement steps 1 and 3. (Step 2 is just a simple move.) We do steps 1 and 3 by using the same algorithm, except with one fewer disc."

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your question is, but here's my best way to visualize the moves in the towers of hanoi:

Arrange the pegs in a triangle like this:

```
     A     C

        B
```

Now, each time you move a disk, it's going to move either clockwise or counter-clockwise.

RULE 1:  A single disk will move in only one direction -- clockwise or anti-clockwise.

RULE 2:  Alternate disks move in opposite directions.

That means that if disk 1 (the smallest) moves clockwise, then 1, 3, 5, 7... all move clockwise, and 2, 4, 6, 8, ... all move anti-clockwise.

It also means that if the you have an even number of disks, then the largest and smallest move in opposite directions.  Otherwise they move in the same direction.  This makes it easy to figure out which way the first move goes.

RULE 3: Always move the biggest disk you can, in its proper direction.

Rule 3 determines the pattern of which disk moves.  It's 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, ...  You start with all 1s, and replace every 2nd 1 with a 2.  Then replace every 2nd 2 with a 3, etc.  If you count in binary with a bit for each disk: 000 001 010 011 100... then at each step, the highest bit that changes corresponds to the largest disk that moves.  If you start at all 0s, then you're done when you get to all 1s.

These rules actually make it very easy to solve the problem without any recursion at all.  They also teach something about recursive vs. iterative solutions:  The recursive solution is usually easier to formulate and understand.  The iterative solution is often more efficient, but requires a deeper insight.